# Querying parameters from one table to display all data from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do this:

query user registration table to find a match for the current user, as well as get the user designation (from the same row and table). Then if user designation equals "1", query the "1_ads" table and show all ads from that table. else if user designation equals "2", query and show all the ads from "2_ads" table.

Please Help or direct me to a hint.